# How to horizontally swap two halves of an image in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I couldn't find any existing answers on how to do this so I wrote my own code already which is down below. This might not be the fastest way to do it but it works well.

Comment: `This might not be the fastest way to do it but it works well` - sounds like your code is working. What is your question?

Comment: There is no question. It is an answer for people who have a similar problem in the future or people can submit improvements upon this code because there might be better ways to do it.

Comment: then post the answer as a real answer (not inside the question), and accept it.

Comment: As @Miki states. This should be an answer, *not* a question. It is perfectly acceptable to write a question, and self-answer it (and accept your own answer)

Comment: Ok I posted it as an answer now but I can't accept it within 2 days and I'm probably going to forget about it but at least the code is there. I'm just posting it to help people with a similar issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`numpy.roll()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) can be used to to shift an array circularly in any axis. For a 1D array for example, it can be used as:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(range(10)) 
#  arr = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
arr_2 = np.roll(arr, len(arr)//2)
#  arr_2 = [5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4]
```

The same method can be used to swap two halves of images horizontally:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('Figure.png', 0)
img = np.roll(img, img.shape[1]//2, axis = 1)
```

for swapping vertically, `np.roll(img, img.shape[0]//2, axis = 0)`.

Answer (score 4):

**Swapping:** (required imports: numpy as np, cv2)

```
height, width = image.shape[0:2]
cutW = int(width / 2)
swapped_image = image[0:height, width - cutW:width].copy()
swapped_image = np.hstack((swapped_image, image[0:height, 0:width-cutW]))
```

**image** is the original image that you want to swap. It should be in the OpenCV file format already meaning you should have used cv2.imread() to open the file, or converted it from another image type to opencv

First half width is taken using 1/2 image.shape. This becomes cutW (width)

Then it copies the **last** half of the image into a new image called "swapped_image"

Then it appends the **first** half of the original image to the swapped_image using np.hstack

**optional**: show the images afterwards

```
height, width = image.shape[0:2]
cutW = int(width / 2)
swapped_image = image[0:height, width - cutW:width].copy()
swapped_image = np.hstack((swapped_image, image[0:height, 0:width-cutW]))
cv2.imshow("SwappedImage", swapped_image)
cv2.imshow("Original ", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you want to swap vertically you could do the same with `np.vstack` and selecting half of the height original image instead of the width